# Check Readiness of application in azure service bus subscriber

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, azureservicebus, health-monitoring

I have a scenario wherein I am calling multiple self api from azure service bus event listener in our microservice base project. after all the endpoint of our application and when we call self APIs is fine but I am running in issue whenever we got an event on application startup before all the rest point is ready. Application is throwing an I/O exception as the endpoint is not ready.
i want solution for mechanism wherein we can check application ready or not.

Please find below snippet code

```
    void registerMessageHandlerOnClient(SubscriptionClient receiveClient) throws ServiceBusException, InterruptedException {

    log.debug("registerMessageHandlerOnClient method invoked");
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(binderPropertyConfig.getThreadpool());
    ISessionHandler sessionHandler = new ISessionHandler() {

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessageSession session, IMessage message) {
            
            //I want some logic to wait for service to up 
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyException(Throwable exception, ExceptionPhase phase) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<Void> OnCloseSessionAsync(IMessageSession session) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        }
    };

    receiveClient.registerSessionHandler(sessionHandler, new 
    SessionHandlerOptions(binderPropertyConfig.getConcurrency(), false, 
    Duration.ofMinutes(binderPropertyConfig.getMaxAutoRenewDurationInMinutes())), threadPool);

 }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions for this case either we can make the call to check self-service health i.e by using health endpoint expose by application `actuator`.
or we can implement `[ApplicationListener][1]` which has a method, which will get called once the application is ready.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup 
implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  /**
   * This event is executed as late as conceivably possible to indicate that 
   * the application is ready to service requests.
   */
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    // here your code ...

    return;
  }
}
```

The `onApplicationEvent()` will receive the event once the application is up. so we can have logic wherein we can set some flag and we can use flag as enable point for consumer.

Answer (score 1):

From the tags you added in the question, I assume you are using spring boot. So, a simple solution I can imagine is to add 'Liveness/Readiness Probes' into all your target micro-services. A probe is simply a http endpoint added along with the service to check whether the service is up. You can consider using Spring Boot Actuator (e.g. "/actuator/health/liveness" and "/actuator/health/readiness" http endpoints). Here are few nice posts on that. NOTE: These Liveness and Readiness concepts are not only applicable to Kubernetes, but they are generally useful, regardless of the deployment platform.

- [Liveness and Readiness Probes with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot)
- [Liveness and Readiness Probes in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-liveness-readiness-probes)
- [How to enable Liveness and Readiness Probes in a Spring Boot Application](https://medium.com/@salarai.de/how-to-enable-liveness-and-readiness-probes-in-a-spring-boot-application-a40cf3423db3)

Once you enable that in the target services, then in the source event listener, you can wait for the readiness of those services before registering message handler.

```java
void registerMessageHandlerOnClient(SubscriptionClient receiveClient) throws ServiceBusException, InterruptedException {

    log.debug("registerMessageHandlerOnClient method invoked");
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(binderPropertyConfig.getThreadpool());
    ISessionHandler sessionHandler = new ISessionHandler() {

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessageSession session, IMessage message) {
            
            // make a REST (HTTP GET) call to "/actuator/health/liveness" endpoint of the target service(s) 
            // to check if up, if not, wait and repeat until up 
            // or give up after x retries with desired error handling logic
            ...
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyException(Throwable exception, ExceptionPhase phase) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<Void> OnCloseSessionAsync(IMessageSession session) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        }
    };

    // make a REST call (HTTP GET) to "/actuator/health/readiness" endpoint of the target service(s) 
    // to check if ready, if not, wait and repeat until ready 
    // or give up after x retries with desired error handling logic.

    receiveClient.registerSessionHandler(sessionHandler, new 
    SessionHandlerOptions(binderPropertyConfig.getConcurrency(), false, 
    Duration.ofMinutes(binderPropertyConfig.getMaxAutoRenewDurationInMinutes())), threadPool);

 }
```